# Mathematica quits calculation automatically

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, block, limit

I have this little program that is adopted from a Wolfram demonstrations project (link here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PercolationOnASquareGrid/).

I want to see what happen if I increase the matrix size to 1000 or even above but Mathematica quits me. If I made the change inside Manipulate, it just showed "Manipulate Aborted". If it is without Manipulate, it quits the Kernel.

I don't if it there is a glitch in my version (9.00) or simply because the limit of Mathematica...

Thanks a lot for your time!!

```
L = 1000;
p1 = 0.6;
seed = 2000;

perColation[{i_, j_}] :=

  If[1 <= i <= L && 1 <= j <= L && a[[i, j]] == 1,
   a[[i, j]] = 2;
   perColation[{i + 1, j}];
   perColation[{i - 1, j}];
   perColation[{i, j + 1}];
   perColation[{i, j - 1}];
   ];

SeedRandom[seed];

Block[{a, $RecursionLimit = Infinity},
 a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {L, L}];
 For[j = 1, j <= L, j++,
  For[i = 1, i <= L, i++,
   If[a[[i, j]] < p1,
    a[[i, j]] = 1,
    a[[i, j]] = 0
    ]]];

 a[[IntegerPart[L/2], IntegerPart[L/2]]] = 1;
 perColation[{IntegerPart[L/2], IntegerPart[L/2]}];
 ArrayPlot[Transpose[a], ImageSize -> 1000, 
  ColorRules -> {0 -> White, 1 -> White, 2 -> Red}]]
```

Comment: With L=3003 I consistently see the same math kernel exit in Win7 with 8 gig and nothing much except MMA and Task Manager running. The total memory being used doesn't take everything before it fails. I would suggest you very politely contact Wolfram Support with exactly the code that fails every time. Don't tell them "I found a bug" or you will make them mad and they will probably deny it and refuse to do anything about it. Say you are confused and this seems odd that it the math kernel disappears and you would like to know if you have done something wrong. Remove ArrayPlot to make it simpler.

Comment: ultimately this is a *cute* demonstration of recursive functions, but not a viable algorithm for solving this problem for large n.  Its not clear from your question if you are seeking better approaches or if you just want to understand the memory issue.

Comment: aside (unrelated to the memory issue) you cant start in the middle like that- reason being the start pixel might not happen to be on the connected path.  In the example the entire top/bottom rows are initialized to 1 and you need to start at one end.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is a memory limit issue similar to one that I have experienced in an industrial setting (although different information provided might lead to a different conclusion). For context, if you haven't, you may want to have a look at the following post from Mathematica [that talks loosely about the limits of Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheLimitsOfMathematica.html) or reach out to their team directly for help. As they note:

"Memory space is the most common limiting factor in Mathematica calculations. Time can also, however, be a limiting factor. You will usually be prepared to wait a second, or even a minute, for the result of a calculation. But you will less often be prepared to wait an hour or a day, and you will almost never be able to wait a year."

They also note, in terms of behavior:

"If your computer does run out of memory in the middle of a calculation, most versions of Mathematica have no choice but to stop immediately. As a result, it is important to plan your calculations so that they never need more memory than your computer has."

This explanation would account for your program quitting automatically during execution.